# Regarding Inflate Exception

Tags: android, inflate-exception

This is the following xml file because of which exception comes.In this,scroll textview has some problem  because of which it gives the inflator exception.Please help me.I think that the problem in code relies in com.sevya.alertman.ScrollingTextView.please just check the following xml file and tell me the solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:background="#cdcdcd" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Volume -->

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:background="@drawable/background" 
                    android:clickable="false" 
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="0dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="5" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="0dp" 
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:layout_weight="7.5" 
                        android:gravity="bottom" 
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                        android:text="Default Volume" 
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" 
                        android:textColor="#2E2E2E" 
                        android:textSize="19dp"/>

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textview_volume_settings" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_weight="2.5" 
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
                        android:text=""/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                     android:layout_height="0dp" 
                     android:layout_weight="5">

                    <SeekBar 
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_volume_settings" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                        android:max="100" 
                        android:maxHeight="9dp" 
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                        android:paddingRight="10dp" 
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" 
                        android:thumb="@xml/thumb_style"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="1dp" 
                    android:background="#000000"/>


                <!-- Ringtone -->

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_ringtone_settings" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:background="@drawable/background" 
                    android:clickable="true" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="60dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="7.5" 
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:weightSum="10">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:layout_weight="5" 
                        android:gravity="bottom" 
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                        android:text="Default Ringtone" 
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" 
                        android:textColor="#2E2E2E" 
                        android:textSize="19dp"/>

                   <com.sevya.alertman.ScrollingTextView 
                       android:id="@+id/textview_ringtone_settings" 
                       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                       android:layout_weight="5" 
                       android:ellipsize="marquee" 
                       android:fadingEdge="horizontal" 
                       android:gravity="top" 
                       android:lines="1" 
                       android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
                       android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                       android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
                       android:text="@string/defaultringtone" 
                       android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" 
                       android:textColor="#2E2E2E"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="0dp" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_weight="2.5" 
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="40dp" 
                        android:contentDescription="@string/downarrow" 
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="1dp" 
                    android:background="#000000"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

When I run the code, I got the following error. Can you please tell me what can I do to remove these exception:

```
06-03 08:37:40.161: E/ERROR(9515): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #125: Error inflating class com.sevya.alertman.ScrollingTextView
```

This is the error that I got when I run a program.

Comment: What you gave us is called markup, not code.  What your error describes is a Java class, which is code.  However, that code is not here.  Have you tried searching for answers?  The error might also relate to your markup, but we have no way of knowing that at the moment.

Comment: @TonyStark 06-03 09:02:22.321: E/ERROR(9515): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #125: Error inflating class com.sevya.alertman.ScrollingTextView

Comment: i think u have not defined the scrolling Textview in java class

Comment: put ur class and xml and error i will make it to you.

Comment: @TonyStark hey thanks.my problem gets solved!!!actually there is a problem in package name.Thanks a lot!!